# Autocomplete textbox using jQuery and ASP.NET Razor Syntax procedurally

Tags: jquery, json, razor, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to create an autocomplete function that retrieves all matching DVD Titles from my database (DVD table). I am using the ASP.NET Razor syntax (Not using MVC). I have attempted this, with no success. Would really appreciate some help. Here is what I currently have:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="dvdTitles" class="custom-field"/>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#dvdTitles').autocomplete({
            source: function (query, process) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'getDVDTitles.cshtml',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: 'term=' + term,
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    async: true,
                    success: function(data) {
                        process(data)
                    }
                });
            }   
        });
```

**ASP.NET Razor (getDVDTitles.cshtml)**

```
@{
var database = Database.Open("SQLServerConnectionString");
var term = Request.Form["term"];
var sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM DVD WHERE dvd_title like '%"+term+"%'";

var output  = database.Query(sqlQuery);

Json.Write(output);
}
```